# How to draw dice in java?

Tags: java

[Red Dice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foAtZ.png) I've been working on a craps game for class and I can't finish the code because I don't know how to draw the actual dots on the die. I have the table and the actual die just not the dots on the dice. I need help on drawing them. And the dice are red. This is what I have:

```
// Draws a given number of dots on this die
private void drawDots(Graphics g, int x, int y, int numDots)
    {
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    int dotSize = dieSize / 4;
    int step = dieSize / 8;
    int x1 = x + step - 1;
    int x2 = x + 3*step;
    int x3 = x + 5*step + 1;
    int y1 = y + step - 1;
    int y2 = y + 3*step;
    int y3 = y + 5*step + 1;

    switch (numDots)
    {
      case 1:
    g.fillOval(x2, y2, dotSize, dotSize);
    break;
  case 2:
    g.fillOval(x3, y1, dotSize, dotSize);
    g.fillOval(x1, y3, dotSize, dotSize);
    break;
  case 3: 
    g.fillOval(x1, y1, dotSize, dotSize);
    g.fillOval(x2, y2, dotSize, dotSize);
    g.fillOval(x3, y3, dotSize, dotSize);
    break;
  case 4:
    g.fillOval(x1, y1, dotSize, dotSize);
    g.fillOval(x3, y3, dotSize, dotSize);
    g.fillOval(x1, y3, dotSize, dotSize);
    g.fillOval(x3, y3, dotSize, dotSize);
    break;
  case 5: 
    g.fillOval(x1, y1, dotSize, dotSize);
    g.fillOval(x2, y2, dotSize, dotSize);
    g.fillOval(x3, y1, dotSize, dotSize);
    g.fillOval(x1, y3, dotSize, dotSize);
    g.fillOval(x3, y3, dotSize, dotSize);
    break;
  case 6:
    g.fillOval(x1, y1, dotSize, dotSize);
    g.fillOval(x2, y1, dotSize, dotSize);
    g.fillOval(x3, y1, dotSize, dotSize);
    g.fillOval(x1, y3, dotSize, dotSize);
    g.fillOval(x2, y3, dotSize, dotSize);
    g.fillOval(x3, y3, dotSize, dotSize);
    break;


}

}
}
```

I don't know what I've done wrong. When I run it the dice roll but they don't show any dots on them.

Comment: It's a snow fairy dancing in a blizzard on top of an igloo in front of a beautiful snow and ice palace.  Issue is, it's all white and blends in together perfectly.  So we can't quite tell if it is indeed a blank sheet of paper or a marvelous painting with intricate details.

Comment: Are you sure this method is being called?  Add a `System.out.println("ducks may moo sometimes");` at the start of the method.  Also set the color to something that isn't anywhere else on the screen, if the background is white set the dots to black, in case they're rendering off of the dice.

Comment: Another issue you may have, are you drawing the dots after or before the dice?  If it's before, the dice will draw over them and hide the dots.  If you provide more code we can have a better understanding of what your issue is

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my issue. My Die.java class was not saying what it needed. Thank you for the help though!

originally my class said:

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Die
{
  private final static Random random = new Random();
  public Die()
{

}
  public int getRoll()
 {
   return random.nextInt(6)+1;
  }
  public int getNumDots()
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
  }
}
```

When it should have said:

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Die
{
  private int sides;
  {
  }

    public void roll()
    {
      sides = (int)(Math.random()* 6 +1);
    }
    public int getNumDots()
    {
      return sides;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you please clarify "My Die.java class was not saying what it needed"? Just in case someone has difficulty with drawing in the future, being more specific here could help them troubleshoot or look elsewhere for a different question if this answer didn't meet their needs.

Comment: Don't use Random. Use SecureRandom instead.

Comment: @Kuetbach why would you use SecureRandom instead of Random? Why is that better?